# compositing without auto render option

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, image, compositing-nodes

I am making an image sequence . in compositing I don't have auto render checkbox.
how can I bring up that check box?[image]

Answer (score 4):

Options Tab> Performance> Auto Render.
[image]